# Exception can not be resolved to a variable inside a method. When the method is called it is always chosen the exception case

Tags: java, exception

I have to impolment quite a complex program and the method MammalFactory is given entirely. because of the thrwon exception I get an error and I do not how to solve it and go on solving the rest of the tasks. It says exception can not be resolved to a variable. [enter image description here][https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9lo6.png]

```
package javasmmr.zoowsome.services.factories;
import javasmmr.zoowsome.models.animals.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MammalFactory extends SpeciesFactory 
{
public Animal getAnimal(String type)
{
    if(Constants.Animals.Mammals.Cow.equals(type))
    {
        return new Cow();
    }
    else if(Constants.Animals.Mammals.Monkey.equals(type))
    {
        return new Monkey();
    }
    else if(Constants.Animals.Mammals.Tiger.equals(type))
    {
        return new Tiger();
    }
    else
      { 
        throw new Exception("Invalid animal exception!");
      }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Post it as text here instead.

Comment: It looks like you are using different quotation marks than `"`. Did you copy that code from some article or document?

Comment: Yes, from the pdf with my homework. The code was given. I changed it and now i get "Unhandled exception type Exception

Comment: Then google this error message. Google "Java exception tutorial", to understand how to deal with exception, and how they work.